# CAML query returning everything?

Tags: development, caml

I am busy messing around with lists and CAML queries:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
SPList list;
SPListItemCollection collection;
query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef name=\"Title\"></FieldRef><Value Type=\"Text\">BLAH BLAH BLAH</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
list = Answers.GetListInstance();
collection =  list.GetItems(query);
foreach (SPListItem item in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["Title"]);
}
```

I'm expecting no matches as I don't have any items with that title.. yet it returns everything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `<Query>` and `</Query>` from your string

Comment: when i do that it throws the error "Not all Fields are properly installed" and this is running of a default list :/

Comment: And change `name` in FieldRef to `Name`

Comment: Man we really need a basic CAML query troubleshooting wiki page... this question comes up pretty frequently. :)

Comment: thanks the Name change worked. Kit i would agree with your thought :D!

Comment: Also, I hope you are not opening a web and then disposing it in `Answers.GetListInstance()` because it will be re-opened when you use the SPList... then you have a memory leak.

Comment: string url = GetListContext();
            string listname = GetListName();
            SPSite site = new SPSite(url);
            return site.RootWeb.Lists[listname];                           That is the code that i run when i retrive the list how should i dispose of the objects i create here ?

Comment: Yeah, you're leaking an SPSite. Try a Using( SPSite site = new SPSite(url)) { ... } block around your GetListInstance() call, and pass the SPSite into it. Also, FYI, you don't need to dispose of the SPWeb object you get from the call to the .RootWeb property - some documentation says that you do, but you really don't. If you used something like the .AllWebs[] collection you would need to dispose if it. Yes, it's pretty confusing. I recommend using SPDisposeCheck to check for memory leaks.

Comment: Oh, and remember the thing about the .RootWeb property - SPDisposeCheck has a bug where it complains if you do dispose of it, and it complains if you don't :o/

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me. You will have to modify it to your needs.

$url = "http://portal.morganstanley.com"
$web = Get-SPWeb $url

$list = $web.Lists["TestList"]

$query = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery

$query.Query = @"

 
  
  2
 


 

"@

$items = $list.GetItems($query);
Write-Host $items.Count